# Changing ToC numbering style

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I am using the document class `book`.

If I start a new chapter using `\chapter{Chapter 1}`, I get something like

[image]

where the two "Chapter 1" looks redundant.

Since the top one of the two "Chapter 1" is generated by default, I switched to just `\chapter{}`, but then the TOC entry of the chapter is just `1`. I want the toc entry of it to still be `Chapter 1`.

Is it possible to change the TOC entry numbering style like `enumerate`? Because for `enumerate` I could write

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{Chapter \arabic{enumi}}
```

and the numbering automatically includes the word "Chapter".

---

If I could get rid of the default generated copy of "Chapter 1", that would also work. But I prefer to let the code do the enumeration automatically instead of manually typing "Chapter x" every time.

Comment: Any chance you could start by making the argument of `\chapter` more informative? E.g., `\chapter{Introduction}` or `\chapter{Conclusion}` or whatever? Many readers tend to truly appreciate receiving visual signposts of what lies ahead.

Comment: @Mico yeah I could do that. I was typing up solutions for a textbook so I thought I would skip the actual names of the chapters. But yeah, that would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One ad hoc solution is adding

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  { \tiny }%
  {\hspace{1ex}%
   }%
  {1pt}%
  {\bfseries\Huge}%
```

to the preamble and start each chapter with
`\chapter{\chaptername\ \thechapter}`

This really just make the default chapter heading small with empty content; doesn't actually get rid of the placeholder element for the default heading.